# Get host IP in docker container

Tags: c, docker

I have a ubuntu container on Ubuntu system. The container acts like client and Ubuntu host system acts like server. So I want to send data to my Host system by using socket programming. To send the data to host sytem I want host Ip. How to get the Host Ip in container. I tried

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

But it returning Docker ip: `172.17.42.1`. But my Host system idp is: `192.168.2.101`. How to get host ip in docker container. You can see below code to know problem.

Ubuntu **Host server.c** looks like below:

```
bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 
listen(listenfd, 10); 
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
```

**Container client.c** looks like below:

```
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // <-- I want place my Host IP here
```

How to get host Ip in container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my Host system idp is: 192.168.2.101

**Your host machine probably has multiple addresses.** It is likely you have `192.168.2.101` on `eth0` or `wlan0` etc. and `172.17.42.1` on docker0 - the virtual interface used to communicate with the containers.

There is no "standard" way to get the other addresses configured on the host; I didn't find any [docker](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) ways to do this.

---

At any rate, the `172.17.42.1` address probably does 100% of what you want - however way you put it your traffic will still flow over that "interface".